# MVP нужно ли применят в малых задачах?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, mvp

Здравствуйте,

в ходе выполнения проекта под андроид возникают небольшие задачи, которые необходимо выполнять в различных местах проекта. Одни и те же задачи часто используются поэтому удобно их выделить в виде отдельной функции, к которой всегда можно обратиться. Проблема в том что повторяющаяся задача выполняет как визуализацию так и расчеты. Т.е. с точки зрения MVP нужно создать 3 класса и 3 интерфейса чтобы к примеру посчитать 2 + 2 и вывести 4 во `View` объект.

Стоит ли для таких малых задач создавать 3 класса **Model, View, Presenter** со своими интерфейсами с точки зрения MVP  ?

Или в небольших задачах можно обойтись к примеру применением `AsyncTask` где разделение визуальной и расчетной частей идет на уровне методов `doInBackground` и `onPostExecute` ?

Моя задача в частности выглядит следующим образом:

необходимо взять несколько `View` объектов `view1`, `view2` и какое-то значение типа `int` `integer1` в виде параметров. Извлечъ из `view1` значение `integer2` сравнить с `integer1` и результат вывести во `view2`.

Заранее благодарен всем за ответы.

---

**Переформулировка вопроса**

С точки зрения **MVP** и **unit** тестов стоит ли для малых задач типа 2 + 2 и вывод результата 4 во **view** объект создавать 3 класса **Model, View, Presenter** для разделения бизнес логики и визуальной части ?

Или для таких несущественных задач можно не проводить **unit** тестов, а следовательно есть возможность объединить визуальную часть и бизнес логику в одной функции и не усложнять работу созданием **MVP** шаблона из 3 классов **Model, View, Presenter**.

Comment: Вы должны принимать решение из соображений практичности и отимального решения задачи, а не каких то условностей и "раз есть какой-то патерн, значит надо применить". Ваш код - ваши правила. В идеале задача должна быть решена самым оптимальным способом, если какой-то паттерн помогает достичь этого, его можно использовать, если без него будет оптимальнее, не стоит его притягивать за уши и усложнять код только для того, чтобы следовать "канонам"

Comment: @pavlofff,  спасибо большое за ответ. Я пока нахожусь на начальной стадии обучения и мне трудно сказать, какие плюсы мне даст MVP. Мне хочется сразу учиться создавать "правильный" код, как рекомендуют более продвинутые программисты. А потом наверное с опытом придет осознание зачем конкретно нужно **MVP**. Как я понял помимо масштабируемости и структурируемости **MVP** позволяет проводить **unit** тесты.

Comment: С точки зрения **unit** тестов  стоит ли выполнять задачу 2 + 2 и вывод значения 4 во **view** объект в одной функции или нужно создавать 3 класса `Model, View, Presenter` для разделения визуальной части и бизнес логики ?

Comment: Ваш вопрос сродни "Нужно ли составлять дизайн-проект, просчитывать сопромат, нанимать прораба, планировать логистику и полное соблюдение техники безопасности, чтобы забить гвоздь и повесить картину". Все определяется масштабом проекта и целями.

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо за ответ. Получается ни всегда нужно следовать канонам **MVP** и в ряде случаев можно сделать исключения если как говорят "Овчинка выделки не стоит".

Comment: Сама по себе архитеутура андроид-приложения естественным образом реализует паттерн MVC (model - view - controller) для представления данных на экране, где модель - собственно данные, вью - виджет на разметке и контроллер - активити или фрагмент, который связывает виджет и данные и управляет ими. Я к тому, что если вам нужен паттерн, то он есть. MVP "не родной" для андроид, почему вы выбрали его?

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо. C MVP по сравнению c MVC легче писать unit тесты и визуальная часть сильнее разделена от бизнес логики. Опять со слов других программистов, например так утверждается  [в этом материале](http://java-help.ru/model-view-presenter-android-part-1/). Еще есть ряд других сайтов, где утверждается, что MVP лучше.